# Como posso está resolvendo estes Erros no Unity 5 e adicionando esses componentes?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomParticlePoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float normalizedTime;

    void OnValidate()
    { 
        particleSystem.Simulate(normalizedTime, true, true);
    }
}
```

[image: Console]

[image: Problema que aparece uqnado aperto o Play]

O Error também aparece quando inicio o programa

Answer (score 1):

#### Como resolver o erro

Este erro ocorre porque não fez conversão quando você mandou abrir este projeto no Unity 5.

Quando você abre um projeto de uma versão antiga do Unity, ele dirá que existe algumas coisas obsoletas e pergunta se você quer converter para a mais recente. Quando não se converte ele mantem a estrutura antiga, que acaba resultando em erro em alguns casos.

No erro que você marcou é sobre a forma de se trabalhar com o particle system.

Antigamente você podia fazer uma chamada dele direto conforme você marcou em amarelo, agora você precisa chamar o GetComponent.

> http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html

Teu código ficaria assim

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomParticlePoint : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float normalizedTime;


    void OnValidate()
    {
        GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Simulate (normalizedTime, true, true);
    }
}
```

#### Como adicionar o componente

Para teu código funcionar `GetComponent` o objeto em que você pendurou teu script também precisa ter o componente que você está pedindo.

Aqui tem um vídeo ensinando a trabalhar com o componente `Particle System`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-Kl5jQ2A8k